# Invalid object when adding geoJSON data on a Leaflet map with Django serializer

Tags: django, leaflet, geojson, geodjango

I'm developing a Django application using Leaflet and Postgresql / PostGIS. When I'm trying to add a MultiLineString layer on a map sending a GeoJSON Feature Collection object, it raises an invalid object error.
At first my views.py:

```
from geonode.geoloc.models import Transport
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.serializers import serialize

class LookupView(FormView):
    template_name = 'geoloc/lookupresults.html'
    form_class = LookupForm

    def get(self, request):
        return render_to_response('geoloc/lookup.html',      RequestContext(request))

def form_valid(self, form):
    # Get data
    latitude = form.cleaned_data['latitude']
    longitude = form.cleaned_data['longitude']

    # Look up roads
    roads =  Transport.objects.all()[0:5]

    roads_json = serialize('geojson', roads,
               fields=('geom',))

    # Render the template
    return self.render_to_response({
                              'roads_json': roads_json
                             }, content_type = 'json')
```

my template when the form is valid:

```
{% extends "geoloc/geoloc_base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load leaflet_tags %}
{% leaflet_js %}
{% leaflet_css %}

<div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
<script>
  var geojsonFeature = "{{ roads_json }}";
  var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
  L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'}).addTo(mymap);
  var myroads = L.geoJSON().addTo(mymap);
  myroads.addData(geojsonFeature);


 </script>
{% endblock %}
```

When I tested the geoJSON object (that Django serializer sends) in http://geojsonlint.com/, I realized that the object is invalid because of the following lines:

```
 "crs": {
"type": "name",
"properties": {
  "name": "EPSG:4326"
}
```

which as I read is "an old-style crs member and is not recommended". Have I to customize the output of serializer in order not to extract the above lines or there is a more efficient way to succeed that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the above issue following the following steps:

- I converted the geoJSON object in a Python dictionary
- I removed the 'crs' key from the dicionary using pop() method
- I converted the dictionary to the geoJSON object again

The modified code in views.py:

```
roads =  Transport.objects.all()[0:5]

roads_json = serialize('geojson', roads,
           fields=('geom',))

new_roads_json = json.loads(roads_json)
new_roads_json.pop('crs', None)
new_roads_json = json.dumps(new_roads_json)

# Render the template
return self.render_to_response({
                     'new_roads_json': new_roads_json
                      }, content_type = 'json')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found that you can and you should remove the crs line altogether.
As stated [here in RFC7946](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#page-12) all GeoJSON coordinates are considered as WGS 84.

> 4. Coordinate Reference System
>
> The coordinate reference system for all GeoJSON coordinates is a
> geographic coordinate reference system, using the World Geodetic
> System 1984 (WGS 84) [WGS84] datum, with longitude and latitude units
> of decimal degrees.  This is equivalent to the coordinate reference
> system identified by the Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) URN
> urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC::CRS84.  An OPTIONAL third-position element SHALL
> be the height in meters above or below the WGS 84 reference
> ellipsoid.  In the absence of elevation values, applications
> sensitive to height or depth SHOULD interpret positions as being at
> local ground or sea level.
>
> Note: the use of alternative coordinate reference systems was
> specified in [GJ2008], but it has been removed from this version of
> the specification because the use of different coordinate reference
> systems -- especially in the manner specified in [GJ2008] -- has
> proven to have interoperability issues.  In general, GeoJSON
> processing software is not expected to have access to coordinate
> reference system databases or to have network access to coordinate
> reference system transformation parameters.  However, where all
> involved parties have a prior arrangement, alternative coordinate
> reference systems can be used without risk of data being
> misinterpreted.